# How to replace only a part of a Regex matched string in .NET?

Tags: .net, regex, replace

Given the string: "+49 ( 0 ) 162 12345 0162"

And the regex: ^(+\s*4\s*9\s*(\s*0\s*)|+\s*4\s*9|0\s*0\s*4\s*9|0|(\s*0\s*))\s*(15|16|17)

It matches: "+49 ( 0 ) 16"

Now I want to replace everything before 16, so that results in "162 12345 0162".

I have so far:

```
        Regex regex = new Regex( @"^(\+\s*4\s*9\s*\(\s*0\s*\)|\+\s*4\s*9|0\s*0\s*4\s*9|0|\(\s*0\s*\))\s*(15|16|17)");
        string result = regex.Replace( "+49 ( 0 ) 162 12345 0162", "" );
```

But that returns "2 12345 0162".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(15|16|17)` part of your pattern - the second capturing group - matches and captures `16`. Thus, you need to replace with `$2` backreference.

```
string result = regex.Replace( "+49 ( 0 ) 162 12345 0162", "$2" );
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%5C%2B%5Cs*4%5Cs*9%5Cs*%5C%28%5Cs*0%5Cs*%5C%29%7C%5C%2B%5Cs*4%5Cs*9%7C0%5Cs*0%5Cs*4%5Cs*9%7C0%7C%5C%28%5Cs*0%5Cs*%5C%29%29%5Cs*%2815%7C16%7C17%29&i=%2B49%20%28%200%20%29%20162%2012345%200162&r=%242)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Is `(15|16|17)` at the end really necessary? Removing it will give you desired result.

Comment: Yes it's necessary, because I dont want to match i.e. "+49 ( 0 ) 142 12345 0162"